# How to accomplish event/meeting members in ER design?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, diagram

I am trying to design an ER diagram for a school project for Android. The project is all about Attendance Tracking.

I think I created it the best I can, but I have one issue left.

For the project we decided that a user creates an event and for each event there will be members and meetings.

My issue is:

I assigned each event some members and then I want to create a meeting on a specific day and of course since this meeting is about an event it should take the same members of that event. How can I accomplish this?

Example:

> Event01 (Member1, Member2, Memeber3)
>
> Meeting1
>
> Meeting2
>
> Meeting3

All the three meeting should have the same members because they are of the same event but in different dates. How can I record attendance for each member in each meeting?

Here is my ER diagram:

[image: ER diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide what your business rules are.

If attendees at a meeting are assumed to be everyone attending the event where the meeting will happen, then you probably don't want to *store* any link between `member` and `event`.  That information would be redundant according to your business rule.

If attendees at a meeting have to be attendees at the event, but not *all* of them, then you want to store meeting attendees directly.  The best way to enforce this with your schema would be to have an intersection between `meeting` and `event_member`.

Comment: I am trying to understand but, let me add some info here. Suppose the event is a Class, so the members are limited and are pre-registered. So on each class meeting I want to take attendance. Meetings are not predefined, so whenever I want to schedule a new meeting I click add meeting to that event specifies date/time but members are associated automatically.

Comment: @MIH1406 - Thanks for the additional info.  Either attendance is something you handle implicitly or explicitly.  From a schema point of view, you probably want to have child attendance records that intersect between your class registration entry (e.g. `event_member`) and the `class` (instance of meeting).  Whether you choose to automatically create these attendance records when you create the `class` or whether you create them as the attendance is taken is up to your preference.  I'd probably create the records defaulted to "absent" and update them to "present" as needed.